# What special in using storyboard in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

i am new to ios development and the concept of views looks confusing to me. For instance i am creating a 'single view application', now whats special in selecting 'story board'. In short what is the difference in using a viewcontroller and adding multiple viewcontroller screens in it and using a storyboard?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Storyboard is:

A container for all your Scenes (View Controllers, Nav Controllers, TabBar Controllers, etc).

A manager of connections and transitions between these scenes (these are called Segues).

A nice way to manage how different controllers talk to each other.

Storyboards give you a complete look at the flow of your application that you can never get from individual nib files floating around.

A reducer of all the "clutter" that happens when you have several controllers each with it's own nib file.

I have been using Storyboards for awhile now and the ONLY downside is that you can't target iOS 4 or below. Storyboards only work on devices running iOS 5 or better. Other than that, the benefits are many and the downsides are non-existent IMO.

The best tutorial I have seen is [Ray Wenderlich's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1)

Also, if you are a member of the Apple Developer program, check out last years WWDC session on Storyboards (iTunesU), it is awesome.

Another great one (also on iTunesU) is the latest Stanford iOS Application Programming course.

Comment: so u mean that it is a good alternate to using seperate nib files? or does their requirement still exist for some cases? (reason other then iOS 4 compatibility)

Comment: yes it's a good alternate in comarison to several nib files but according to my experience level there are some limitation too with storyboard.for that you can refer this link http://blog.waynehartman.com/archive/2012/01/07/uistoryboard-on-ios-5-the-good-the-bad-and-the.aspx

Answer (score 2):

go through these tutorials about ios 5, he has explained very nice about new features in ios5 and how to use in coding very easily...

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5113/announcing-the-ios-5-feast

Comment: any free tutorials resource :|

Answer (score 0):

By using story board you can create your views and connect them using the single file rather than creating one nib file for one view.

You can google for "story board tutorial iphone" and get lots of tutorial to follow.